# Is there a way to use the Active X controllers TimgEdit, TimgOCR, and Timgscan with Delphi 10.4?

Tags: delphi, activex, delphi-10.4-sydney

Trying to upgrade an application from Delphi 7 to Delphi 10 and this is the only roadblock. I have tried importing components but they don't show under the active x palette. Is there an alternative or way to make this work?

Comment: The Kodak Imaging ActiveX controls are very old and only came with old versions of Windows. There are compatible controls available that work with latter versions but they are not cheap and have per user license fees: http://www.alliancegroup.co.uk/imaging-for-windows-sdk.html  You don't mention which controls you are using or what you did to build a ActiveX packages and install that into the IDE.

Comment: @Brian The controls i'm using are image OCR image edit and image scan. The way I tried to installl the component was to go to components and import components and chose to import ActiveX Control, and then selected the registered Active X controls. I imported the Timgedit , img ocr, and imgscan components but they were no where to be found in the palette selector.

Comment: You just repeated yourself. Don't underestimate that the Windows version you're using now is a much different one than when Delphi 7 was recent.

Comment: List all the steps you did - for example did you install to an existing package or a new package? If a new package was there any error in the IDE when did the install? As for the controls list the actual details - OS running on now, where you got the ActiveX controls as they have not been included since Windows 2000, and at least the description, version, filename etc listed in the import component dialog. Also search the component palate by type a partial component name to see if you just missed it.

Comment: Just giving up on these old unsupported components and moving to Delphi Twain, T canvas and Timage.